# Can't bind to inlineSVG

Tags: angular, svg, ionic3

I'm trying to use inline SVG in ionic 3.3.0/Angular 4.1.2 through the [ng-inline-svg](https://github.com/arkon/ng-inline-svg) package.

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { InlineSVGModule } from 'ng-inline-svg';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, HttpModule, InlineSVGModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
class AppModule {}
```

Template

```
<div class="icon icon-shop" aria-label="My icon" [inlineSVG]="'../../assets/symbol-defs.svg#icon-shop'"></div>
```

And im getting the error

> Can't bind to 'inlineSVG' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

Answer (score 5):

Because of Lazy Loading in Ionic, you need to add the import of InlineSVGModule in every Pages *.module.ts file where you ever use it.

Comment: This response helped me a bunch today. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I have had the same issue also where placing the imports in the app.module worked in an angular-cli app, but not when built in an angular app by webpack.

I resolved it by placing the imports in the component that references a template where you intend to use ng-inline-svg.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where is your template which use are using [inlineSVG] but you should include your component into declarations section of AppModule.
For example your template code is in ShopComponent:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, ShopComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, HttpModule, InlineSVGModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```